# Why do the Specialists not employ firearms?

Tags: fate-the-winx-saga

In *Fate: The Winx Saga*, the Specialists, who appear to occupy soldier and police roles in the Otherworld, use a variety of weapons, including knives, swords, and homing bows. However, they do not seem to use firearms, despite their advantages, such as higher rate of fire.

The problem is clearly not that advanced technology does not function in the Otherworld or is culturally disfavored, since we see things like cell phones and modern vehicles being used around Alfea. In fact, some of it functions extraordinarily well (cell phone calls from the Otherworld to the First World, anyone?) For that matter, the Specialists themselves use what appears to be modern bulletproof body armor and military transport vehicles.

With that in mind, why do Specialists not employ any firearms?